# Stored procedure code works to insert data into table but does not work when called from the stored procedure node

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is the full stored procedure. When I select everything between "set no count on" and "end" it works perfectly and table zLOC_invValue gets updated with 2 lines.

If I try to right click on the stored procedure node and choose to execute, the return value is 0 and the table is not updated. I also get the message that the query is executed successfully.

```
USE [TWL_PROD]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_invValue]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select 'S ' + whse as whse, prod, qtyonhand + qtyunavail as qty ,(avgcost+addoncost) as cost into #stock from openquery ( twllive, 'select whse, prod, qtyonhand,qtyunavail,avgcost,addoncost  from pub.icsw where cono = ''1'' and whse in (''mtl'', ''nob'', ''tdc'', ''oak'')');

select 'NS ' + whse as whse, prod, sum(quantity) as qty, sum( case when quantity > 0 then amount else -1*amount end) as total_value into #nStock from openquery ( twllive, 'select  b.* from pub.icenh a left join pub.icenl b on a.cono = b.cono and a.typecd = b.typecd and a.whse = b.whse and a.prod = b.prod and a.prodcat = b.prodcat and a.seqnoh = b.seqnoh where a.cono = ''1'' and a.typecd = ''n''  and a.whse in (''mtl'', ''tdc'', ''nob'', ''oak'') and a.activefl = 1  ') 
group by whse, prod;

select co_num , abs_num as prod, bin_num, total_qty,total_qty * 1.00 as value, item_type into #3pl from openquery (twllive, 'select a.co_num, a.abs_num, a.total_qty, a.bin_num, b.item_type from pub.inventory a left join pub.item b on a.wh_num = b.wh_num and a.abs_num = b.abs_num where a.co_num = ''1'' and a.wh_num = ''mtl'' and bin_num in ( ''dockexpp'', ''dockexca'', ''docktransi'')');

update #3PL set Value = (g.total_value/g.qty) * a.total_qty from #3PL a inner join #nStock g on a.prod = g.prod  where A.item_type = 'n' and g.whse = 'NS mtl';
update #3PL set Value = (g.cost) * a.total_qty from #3PL a inner join #Stock g on a.prod = g.prod  where A.item_type = 's' and g.whse = 's mtl' ;

select  co_num, SUM(case when bin_num = 'dockexpp' and item_type = 's' then value else 0 end) as Stock_Plaspak,SUM(case when bin_num = 'dockexpp' and item_type = 'n' then value else 0 end) as NS_Plaspak , SUM(case when bin_num = 'dockexca' and item_type = 's' then value else 0 end) as Stock_Caratrans , SUM(case when bin_num = 'dockexca' and item_type = 'N' then value else 0 end) as NS_Caratrans,  SUM(case when bin_num = 'docktransi' and item_type = 's' then value else 0 end) as Stock_Transit,SUM(case when bin_num = 'docktransi' and item_type = 'n' then value else 0 end) as NS_transit into #3PL1 from #3PL group by co_num;

select * into #temp from (
select 1 as cono, whse, SUM(total_value) as value from #nStock group by whse
union all 
select 1 as cono, whse, SUM(qty * cost) as value from #Stock group by whse 
union all 
select 1 as cono,'S-3PL' as whse,  SUM(case when item_type = 's' then value else 0 end) as value from #3pl
union all 
select 1 as cono,'NS-3PL' as whse,  SUM(case when item_type = 'n' then value else 0 end)as value from #3pl ) "a";

update #temp set value = ((select value from #temp where whse = 'ns mtl') - (select value from #temp where whse = 'ns-3pl') ) where whse = 'ns mtl';
update #temp set value = ((select value from #temp where whse = 's mtl') - (select value from #temp where whse = 's-3pl') ) where whse = 's mtl';


select cono,[NS MTL],[NS NOB],[NS OAK],[NS TDC],[S MTL],[S NOB], [S OAK], [S TDC] into #stock1 from #temp
pivot (max(value) for whse in ([NS MTL],[NS NOB],[NS OAK],[NS TDC],[S MTL],[S NOB], [S OAK], [S TDC])) as PivotTable;

insert into zloc_InvValue select * from ( 
select 'Stock: ' as [type], GETDATE() as [date], a.[S MTL] as MTL,a.[S NOB] as NOB, a.[S OAK] as OAK, a.[S TDC] as TDC, b.Stock_Plaspak as [3PL- Plaspak], b.Stock_Caratrans as [3PL- Caratrans], b.Stock_transit as [3PL- transit] from #stock1 a full outer join #3PL1 b on a.cono = b.co_num
union all
select 'Non-Stock: ' , GETDATE() , a.[NS MTL],a.[NS NOB], a.[NS OAK], a.[NS TDC], b.NS_Plaspak, b.NS_Caratrans, b.NS_transit from #stock1 a full outer join #3PL1 b on a.cono = b.co_num ) "a"

drop table #nStock
drop table #stock
drop table #3PL
drop table #3PL1
drop table #temp
drop table #stock1



END
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: I get the standard return value of 0 but no lines are inserted into my table.  Also, if I only select the code within the store procedure, the reqired lines are inserted in the table.

Comment: Where are those temporary tables created? We only have a `DROP` statement for them; seems odd that the SP would simply just drop a bunch of temporary tables. You might want to at least do some formatting of that SQL; everything on one line does make it difficult to read. On a different note [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: I actually thought seeing your procedure would make this better. But this has made your question even worse. If you run that procedure all by itself it will just throw an error because all the temp tables don't exist.

Comment: Here is the full code